# While loop and PHP/MYSQL insert statement

Tags: php, mysql, insert, while-loop

Am I able or how can I create a while loop to run through some insert statemtns. I have some code below that I have tried to use using i++ but I keep getting errors in relation to where I have put $i such as:

> Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string

Its hard to explain the previous code that amounts to this insert setup, but basically I decalre some variables and then they get bind and inserted with the following code but I have like 30 thins that could be inserted hence the while loop. So the outcome should be supplier_name2 - supplier_name30 and same for address etc etc.

```
   while ($i <= 30):
      //LINE TWO
      $suppliername = $this->supplier_name.$i;
      if(!empty($suppliername)){
          $sql0.$i = "INSERT INTO suppliers (supplier_name, supplier_address) 
                          VALUES (:supplier_name.$i, :supplier_address.$i) ";   
          $st0.$i = $conn->prepare ( $sql0.$i );
          $st0.$i->bindValue( ":supplier_name".$i, $this->supplier_name.$i, PDO::PARAM_STR );
          $st0.$i->bindValue( ":supplier_address".$i, $this->supplier_address.$i, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $st0.$i->execute();
          $this->id = $conn->lastInsertId();
          $supplierid.$i = $this->id = $conn->lastInsertId();
        }  
    $i++; 
    endwhile;
```

Any help appreciated.
Ian

Answer (score 1):

Expression `$sql0.$i` will be interpreted as string so PHP will try to use your `PDOStatement` as string.
It's not the way you should use `prepared statements`.

Move your `prepared statement` before loop with some modifications.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO suppliers (supplier_name, supplier_address) 
                      VALUES (:supplier_name, :supplier_address) ";   
$statement = $conn->prepare ( $sql );
```

Then perform `bindValue()` and `execute()` on `$statement` variable. Idea is to declared once and use few times.
Also don't use `$i` in attributes names, it's unnecessary.

Comment: Yes I get an "Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string" on the line that contains " $st0.$i = $conn->prepare ( $sql0.$i );". Not really sure how to put the statement outside the loop while making it loop the require amounts of times

Comment: @snookian Put only lines from my answer outside of loop, anything else stays in loop.

Comment: This add the same line 30 times to the db, I have a table with thrity fields in it, all supplier_name and supplier_address with $i++ so for example supplier_name1, supplier_name2 etc, Now rather than write the statement for each I wanted to create a loop so If they add only the first 10 name and address its adds the first 10, if they add thrity names it adds 30

Comment: @snookian If you assign result of `preapre()` to lets say `$prepared` and then assign values and execute from this variable, then you'll add different rows. You're probably overwriting `$statement` just like you did in your code from question.

Comment: OK Im actually a bit lost

Answer (score 0):

In > `"supplier_name.$i"` the dot is literal. So it becomes "supplier_name.1", "supplier_name.2" etc

In `":supplier_address".$i` the dot is not literal, it is used as the concatenation operator. Hence you get "supplier_name1" and "supplier_name2" etc. Hence no replacement occurs I assume.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, below one insert `supplier_name1 - supplier_name30` in tables.

```
          while ($i <= 30):
              //LINE TWO
              $suppliername = $this->supplier_name.$i;
              $supplier_address = $this->supplier_address.$i;
              if(!empty($suppliername)){
                $sql0 = "INSERT INTO suppliers (supplier_name, supplier_address)
                VALUES (:supplier_name, :supplier_address) ";
                $st0 = $conn->prepare ( $sql0 );
                $st0->bindValue( ":supplier_name", $suppliername, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                $st0->bindValue( ":supplier_address", $supplier_address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $st0.$i->execute();
                        $this->id = $conn->lastInsertId();
                $supplierid = $this->id = $conn->lastInsertId();
              }
              $i++;
          endwhile;
```